# How to use endlessScroll on dropdown on select list?

Tags: jquery

I found [this really neat little plugin](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) today while Googling infinite scrolling.

My question is how can I use this plugin on a dropdown box? I have thousands of records that I obviously don't want to load in the dropdown at once.

Comment: A dropdown? Meaning a `<select>` tag? You can't really... the dropdown menu itself is all handled by the browser. If you want to use a custom javascript dropdown, then yes it's possible. We need more information.

Comment: If you have thousands of records, you shouldn't be using a dropdown at all. That violates UX guidelines of every platform there is.

Comment: Thanks Diego. What would you suggest? I'm being told what to do by superiors, but I would love to tell them a better way to do this.

Comment: @user1382770 That depends on what the data is. Ideally you should be able to first filter it down to a manageable number of selections (less than 15 just to throw a number out there) before displaying it in a dropdown.

Comment: jquery has a good example of a combobox on their autocomplete demo page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an AJAX search tool.